# Line break in a SSI

Tags: nginx, ssi

So, I'm including a `.log` file in a HTML page with

```
<!--#include file="/logs.access.log" -->
```

It works fine, except for one thing : there is no line break after a log. So, I just have a long line of logs.

Quite annoying to read... Would it have a solution to automatically add line break after a log (like a `tail`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because your log file is plain text, and it's being displayed as html, which doesn't preserve line breaks.  Try using `<pre><!--#include file="/logs.access.log" --></pre>` and see if that helps.